# ljmp syntax in gcc inline assembly

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler, segments

I was thinking of using a far jump to set the code segment (CS) register. Getting into why I'm doing this and why I'm dealing with segmentation at all would take a while, so bear with me and consider it an academic exercise. I can't seem to get the syntax right.

`Error: suffix or operands invalid for 'ljmp'`

I know it's foolish to put `cs` into another register, but I figured I'd try it since using `%0` wasn't working (the `ax` register doesn't work either).

I'm looking at some code that compiles fine and this is driving me crazy, since I thought `ljmp` would be the same: `__asm volatile ( "lcall $0x8, $far_call" );`

I would of course welcome other hacky ways of affecting the CS register.

```
void set_cs(u16 cs) {
    __asm__ volatile (
        "mov %0, %%ax \n\t"
        "ljmp %%ax, $fake_label \n\t"
        "fake_label: \n\t"
        :
        : "r" (cs)
        : "ax"
    );
}
```

Comment: Inline assembly is a pain in the ass; why not just write real assembly routines in real assembly files?

Comment: Are you sure it is encodable with registers instead of immediates  by reading the Intel manual? I still can't decode that thing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear ljmp requires constants to work, while this generates more code and is obviously not particularly safe, this appears to work as when I enter a value that is not the current cs value, the application crashes. It uses an immediate value instead:

`#define set_cs( cs ) asm volatile ( "ljmp %0, $fake_label \n\t fake_label: \n\t" :: "i"(cs) )`

It's not as elegant as I assume you wanted it to be, and depends entirely on what you're trying to do. I can't imagine this ever being useful or even working if you're compiling this to run under linux/windows.

Comment: Far jumps are used in freestanding code (e.g. operating system code) to specify code segment selectors (even in x86_64 they are used to specify privilege level, i.e. kernel/user space).  I agree, this does not make much sense in user space code...